# How to prevent wp_insert_post from creating a new post every second?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-insert-post

I am trying to create a simple plugin that creates only one new post. The code I have written creates a the same new post every second. Below is the code I have. What would need to be added so it creates only one post?

```
<?php
/**
*@package blog-poster
*/
/*
Plugin Name: Blog Poster
Plugin URI: http://www.litliving.com
Description: This is a plugin for Litliving customers that allows for blog posts to be automatically posted.
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Ben Smith
Author URI: http://www.bengsmith.com
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH') ){
  die;
}


function AddThisPage() {
    global $wpdb; // Not sure if you need this, maybe

    $page = array(
        'post_title' => 'My post!!!',
        'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'post',
    );

    wp_insert_post($page);

}

add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'AddThisPage' );

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'AddThisPage' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin does no checking at all, such as “does the post already exists?”
Accordingly, it creates a post each time WordPress is called.

There is a system called *WordPress heartbeat*, which contacts the server every few seconds. Your plugin is called each time, and a post is created.

For reference, the [Heartbeat doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/heartbeat-api/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. Ironically, after I had posted this I found the answer. I needed to create an if else statement at the bottom. I write

```
$page_exists = get_page_by_title( $page['post_title'] );

    if( $page_exists == null ) {

        $insert = wp_insert_post( $page );
        if( $insert ) {

        }
    } else {

    }
```